# query execution drastically slows down with order by

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the following query

```
SELECt
  SUM(GA) AS GA1,
  sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd
FROM
  sales_data_mkt 
WHERE activity_dt between '2015-09-01' 
  AND '2015-09-30'
    and sales_data_mkt.MKT_CD is not null
GROUP BY sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd
HAVING ga1 > 0 
LIMIT 10
```

**`Its Explain`**
Execution Time: 6-7 sec

```
id  select_type table           type     possible_keys                  key        key_len      ref     rows       Extra;
1   SIMPLE      sales_data_mkt  range    ACTIVITY_DT,REGION_CD,MKT_CD   MKT_CD     13           null    4954774    Using where
```

Now i add `order by` clause

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
  SUM(GA) AS GA1,
  sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd
FROM
  sales_data_mkt 
WHERE activity_dt BETWEEN '2015-09-01' 
  AND '2015-09-30'
    AND sales_data_mkt.MKT_CD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd
HAVING ga1 > 0 
ORDER BY SUM(ga) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

**`Its Explain`**
Execution Time: 600 sec

```
id  select_type   table             type     possible_keys                  key     key_len   ref     rows      Extra;
1   SIMPLE        sales_data_mkt    range    ACTIVITY_DT,REGION_CD,MKT_CD   MKT_CD  13        null    4954774   Using where\; Using temporary\; Using filesort
```

The `sales_data_mkt` has 10M rows. The minumum `activity_dt` is **Jan 01 2015** and the max is **Oct 06 2015**. Basically about 1M rows per month.

The Following index exist:

1. area_cd (area_cd, activity_dt)
2. activity_dt (activity_dt, mkt_cd)
3. region_cd (region_cd, mkt_cd_activity_dt)
4. mkt_cd (mkt, activity_dt)

Here is the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_data_mkt` (
  `ACTIVITY_DT` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country_Cd` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USA',
  `AREA_CD` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AREA_DESC` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION_CD` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION_DESC` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MKT_CD` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MKT_NAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_tier` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SLS_DIST_CHNL_TYPE_CD` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PPlan_Type` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREPAID_IND` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edge_taken_ind` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Desc` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Plan_Tier` varchar(26) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unlimited_to_Others_cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_UP_Cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_Down_Cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lines` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NetAdd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VOL_DE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INVOL_DE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_ATT_Leap` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_Sprint_Nextel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_TMobile_MetroPcs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_OtherCarriers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_ATT_Leap` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_Sprint_Nextel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_TMobile_MetroPcs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_OtherCarriers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Net_Sales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Eligible_Net_Sales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Net_Sales_All` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Basic_To_Smart` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AAL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `New_To_VZ` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trade_In` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unlimited_to_Others` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_Up` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_Down` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `AREA_CD` (`AREA_CD`,`ACTIVITY_DT`),
  KEY `ACTIVITY_DT` (`ACTIVITY_DT`,`MKT_CD`),
  KEY `REGION_CD` (`REGION_CD`,`MKT_CD`,`ACTIVITY_DT`),
  KEY `MKT_CD` (`MKT_CD`,`ACTIVITY_DT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What indexes do i need to improve performace?

`Note:` Just like this query for the `GA` column i have other queries for other columns in the table. This makes me scared on creating an index on `GA` and every other KPI column in the table.

Comment: Some non-index performance notes.  Decrease the size of the table by doing _when appropriate_:  `NOT NULL`; `CHARACTER SET ascii`; shorter INTs (`TINYINT`, etc); `UNSIGNED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the index i think you need one on the fields :

```
  activity_dt, mkt_cd, ga
```

in this order. In this way the select should resolve all the info need in the index avoiding the access to table data.

Comment: i have similar scripts for the other columns than GA. About 30 other metrics from this table. Is adding index on all of them sustainable?

Comment: If you have an index with this sequence of field when work, if the other indexes have not this sequence they are not much usefl. I should evaluate but.... add an index does not in itself mean a decrease in performance if not during insert, update and delete where individual actions must be repeated for all the indexes. This would see the structure of the database and query the most important and build on these indexing more appropriate, also it is used to check whether the right index and eventulamente mofidicare leggeremente the query to direct the use of the index more suitable.

Comment: Did this and as excepted the query time came down. Additionally i partitioned my database.

Comment: down to 6 secs with the covering index from 10 minutes. Additionally also partitioned my table on the activity_dt.